# Does Firebird Embedded Server compresses the Data?

Tags: sqlite, firebird, firebird2.5

I am looking for an SQLite Alternative. SQlite, while it is good, it does not compress it's database, making 6 months worth of data almost 3-4 GB in my case.

Does anyone know whether the Firebird Embedded Server compressed it's database?

Comment: Do you really mean compress, or do you mean cleanup old data/garbage collection?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, Firebird records are [RLE compressed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run-length_encoding). Don't think it's going to have a huge effect on your DB size though, you have to test.

Additionally you can use [BLOB filters](http://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/reference_material/html/langrefupd25-ddl-filter.html) to compress BLOBs so it's transparent to the user. Read more about BLOB filters from the [IB 6 user manual](http://www.firebirdsql.org/en/reference-manuals/).